# I tried gay oral sex before several times before but I regret it

Tags: homosexuality

I used to be depressed and had a lot of anxiety I needed something to comfort me so I tried to have gay sex
Now I regret doing this and I’m trying to be a better Muslim, will Allah ever forgive me for what I did?

Comment: I tried to say allah*

Answer (score 1):

Inshallah brother as soon as you ask for forgivness from your hart, Allah will forgive you and as big as the seen is he will forgive it.

Dont forget after Allah (swt) told us in the holy Quran

> "Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful."

(Quran 39:53)

I hope Allah will forgive and accept all of your good deads